# Update with lag

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle10g

I would like to set the ACTIVE value of a table as follow:

- If `FLAG=E` => `ACTIVE=1` and for any subsequent `FLAG` values, until `FLAG=H`
- If `FLAG=H` => `ACTIVE=0` and for any subsequent `FLAG` values, until `FLAG=E`

and so on and so forth.

**Example**

```
ID | FLAG | ACTIVE
---+------+-------
1  | E    | 1
2  | V    | 1
3  | H    | 0
4  | V    | 0
5  | E    | 1
6  | S    | 1
7  | V    | 1
8  | D    | 1
9  | H    | 0
```

The value are ordered by date.
For simplicity, I added an ID column to get the column order.

**Question**

What can be the SQL update statement ?

Note:

The business rule can also be expressed as follow:

If for a given row, the count of preceding `E` - the count of preceding `H` is 1, then ACTIVE is 1 for this row, 0 otherwise.

Comment: You haven't shown how you determine the ordering - preceding and subsequent need to be defined, presumably by another column you haven't included?

Comment: Thanks. The column are ordered by a date. For simplicity, I added an `ID` column to get the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `active` value with [the `last_value()` analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions085.htm#SQLRF00655):

```
select id, flag,
  last_value(case when flag = 'E' then 1 when flag = 'H' then 0 end) ignore nulls
    over (order by id) as active
from your_table;
```

As a demo:

```
create table your_table (id, flag) as
          select 1, 'E' from dual
union all select 2, 'V' from dual
union all select 3, 'H' from dual
union all select 4, 'V' from dual
union all select 5, 'E' from dual
union all select 6, 'S' from dual
union all select 7, 'V' from dual
union all select 8, 'D' from dual
union all select 9, 'H' from dual;

select id, flag,
  last_value(case when flag = 'E' then 1 when flag = 'H' then 0 end) ignore nulls
    over (order by id) as active
from your_table;

        ID F     ACTIVE
---------- - ----------
         1 E          1
         2 V          1
         3 H          0
         4 V          0
         5 E          1
         6 S          1
         7 V          1
         8 D          1
         9 H          0
```

You can use the same thing for an update, though a merge is probably going to be simpler:

```
alter table your_table add active number;

merge into your_table
using (
  select id,
    last_value(case when flag = 'E' then 1 when flag = 'H' then 0 end) ignore nulls
      over (order by id) as active
  from your_table
) tmp
on (your_table.id = tmp.id)
when matched then update set active = tmp.active;

9 rows merged.

select * from your_table;

        ID F     ACTIVE
---------- - ----------
         1 E          1
         2 V          1
         3 H          0
         4 V          0
         5 E          1
         6 S          1
         7 V          1
         8 D          1
         9 H          0
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a4f10b915c0fc5dbe0b43130893f324).

---

You said your real data is actually ordered by a date, and I guess there are multiple flags for each of multiple IDs, so something like this is probably more realistic:

```
create table your_table (id, flag_time, flag) as
          select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:00', 'E' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:01', 'V' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:02', 'H' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:03', 'V' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:04', 'E' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:05', 'S' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:06', 'V' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:07', 'D' from dual
union all select 1, timestamp '2018-07-04 00:00:08', 'H' from dual;

alter table your_table add active number;

merge into your_table
using (
  select id, flag_time,
    last_value(case when flag = 'E' then 1 when flag = 'H' then 0 end) ignore nulls
      over (partition by id order by flag_time) as active
  from your_table
) tmp
on (your_table.id = tmp.id and your_table.flag_time = tmp.flag_time)
when matched then update set active = tmp.active;

select * from your_table;

        ID FLAG_TIME               F     ACTIVE
---------- ----------------------- - ----------
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:00.000 E          1
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:01.000 V          1
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:02.000 H          0
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:03.000 V          0
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:04.000 E          1
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:05.000 S          1
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:06.000 V          1
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:07.000 D          1
         1 2018-07-04 00:00:08.000 H          0
```

The main difference is the `partition by id` and changing the ordering to use `flag_time` - or whatever your real columns are called.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70800afa2820910983d31d3af333a06f).

---

There is potentially an issue if two flags can share a time; with a timestamp column that's hopefully very unlikely, but with a date the precision of the column may allow it. There isn't much you can do about that though, except maybe get into some logic to break ties by assuming flags should arrive in a certain order, and give them a weighting based on that. Rather off-topic though.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'm getting a `ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function`.

Comment: It's working in the db<>fiddles, so not sure what you are doing differently Check the `over()` clauses you are using.

Comment: Oooops this DB is on 10g. Very sorry. Indeed, checked on Fiddle is work perfectly for 11g. Work for 10g though without `ignore nulls`. Updated the question accordingly. But marked answered and correct! Thanks a lot again. Very useful!

Comment: That analytic function [exists in 10g too](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions073.htm) so I think it ought to still work. I don't have a 10g DB to test against though.

Comment: Work like a charm closing the `last_value(` parenthesis after the `AFTER NULLS`. In others words, with: `last_value(case when flag = 'E' then 1 when flag = 'H' then 0 end IGNORE NULLS )`.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot that; either form is valid from 11g. Glad you were able to resolve that.